# Slanting Rhombus pattern using nested loops. Java

Tags: java

**I am sharing the code for a third person perspective to where the problem may be lying.
I am trying to design a slanting rhombus using *. My output is a not returning slanting as the spaces before the * in each line might not be working.
**

[The Desired output can be seen at the back. My output is also shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlmGC.png)

```
public class file{

 public static void rhombus(int n){
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        //spaces
        for(int j=1; j<=(n-1); j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
            }

        //stars    
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }

 }

 public static void main (String args[]){
   rhombus(5);
 }

}
```

Comment: n-1 doesn't change.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that in the first for loop, where spaces are being printed, the loop variable 'j' is only being compared to (n-1) instead of (n-i). This means that the same number of spaces are being printed on every row, resulting in a diamond shape instead of a slanting rhombus. To fix this, change the comparison in the first for loop to (n-i) so that the number of spaces printed decreases as the row number increases.

You can change it this way

```
public class file{

    public static void rhombus(int n){
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            //spaces
            for(int j=1; j<=(n-i); j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //stars    
            for(int j=1; j<=n; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();  
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        rhombus(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input mate! Appreciate it